# unable to figure out the error in below program

Tags: c++, binary-search

I stuck at a problem [spoj four sum](https://www.spoj.com/problems/SUMFOUR/)
I solved this problem using binary search,for the given test case
INPUT:

6

-45 22 42 -16

-41 -27 56 30

-36 53 -37 77

-36 30 -75 -46

26 -38 -10 62
-32 -54 -6 45

Actual output:3

Expected output:5

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int a[4100],b[4100],c[4100],d[4100];
vector <int> s1,s2;
int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>a[i]>>b[i]>>c[i]>>d[i];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            s1.push_back(a[i]+b[j]);
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            s2.push_back((c[i]+d[j]));
        }
    }
    sort(s1.begin(),s1.end());
    sort(s2.begin(),s2.end());
    int ans = 0;
    for(int v: s1){
        vector <int> ::iterator x = lower_bound(s2.begin(),s2.end(),v);
        vector <int> ::iterator y = upper_bound(s2.begin(),s2.end(),v);
        ans+=y-x;

    }
    cout<<ans<<endl;;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but your algorithm calculates nothing like what's required. For instance given the input `1 1 1 1 1` it produces an answer of `1` which is incorrect since `1 + 1 + 1 + 1` does not equal `0`.